# Loop through multi dimensional array of api response in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an api response aray. where i am trying to loop throgh the array using v-for. I can able to loop thorogh the first iteration but for the second loop i cant do the iteration. hoe can i loop throgh the reciepts object here?
    I have a multi dimensional array

```
//this is my api response
    0:      name : "name",
        address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 10,
                bill : 101, 
        1:  
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 12,
                bill : 101, 

    1:  name : "name",
        address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 13,
                bill : 101, 
        1:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 14,
                bill : 101, 
    2:  name : "name",
        address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 15,
                bill : 101, 
        1:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 16,
                bill : 101,
```

I have tried to loop through the items, but i dont know how to get the child arrays object(in my case reciepts). how can i do this> can anyone help me out?

```
 <ul>
    <li v-for="report in reportResults"> //this is working
       <div class="row " style="background-color: #f4fbee;">
          <div class="col-md-2">{{report.bill_no}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"  v-for="reciepts in reportResults" style="    
             background-color: #fff2f2;"> //this is not working
         <div class="col-md-2" ></div>
         <div class="col-md-2" v-show="reciepts.bill_no==report.bill_no">{{ 
                  reciepts.doc_no}}</div>

<li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop over the sub array and not on global array

```
<div class="row"  v-for="reciepts in report">
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="row"  v-for="reciepts in report">
reciepts.doc_no</div>    //it print nothing

Comment: @2lionel but if i do  `<div class="row" v-for="reciepts in report"> reciepts</div>`  it prints everything....    `{ "reciepts": { "bill_no": "123", "doc_no": "nmkdzl", "paid": 100}`

Comment: Display only what you want : {{receipts.bill_no}}

Comment: its not displying anything

Comment: its bcoz its inside another array called 'reciepts'. how can i access to reciepts

Comment: {{reciepts.reciepts.bill_no}}